# PHP: Split string into array, like explode with no delimiter

Tags: php, string, arrays, split, explode

I have a string such as:

> "0123456789"

And I need to split *each* character into an array.

I, for the hell of it, tried:

```
explode('', '123545789');
```

But it gave me the obvious: **Warning: No delimiter defined in explode)** ..

How would I come across this? I can't see any method off hand, especially just a function.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

```
$array = str_split("0123456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz");
```

[str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) takes an optional 2nd param, the chunk length (default 1), so you can do things like:

```
$array = str_split("aabbccdd", 2);

// $array[0] = aa
// $array[1] = bb
// $array[2] = cc  etc ...
```

You can also get at parts of your string by treating it as an array:

```
$string = "hello";
echo $string[1];

// outputs "e"
```

Comment: Ah. Missed that function, was splitting binary numbers to becalculated in an array, this works well.

Comment: What about encoding?

Comment: PHP doesn't understand encoding. It will just split the string into bytes, so any multi-byte characters will get messed up. PHP6 was supposed to fix that but it didn't happen.

Comment: @kicaj In the comments at http://php.net/mb_split you can see a function written by adjwilli which is supposed to split a UTF8 string into characters.

Answer (score 19):

You can access characters in a string just like an array:

```
$s = 'abcd';
echo $s[0];
```

> prints '**a**'

Comment: Of course, this answer makes no attempt to split a string, it just demonstrates how you can access byte values in a string by their offset.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$str = '123456789';
$char_array = preg_split('//', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: That's really unnecessary, and quite a bit slower then str_split.

Comment: @Erik: Not if you need to get back an empty array in case the `$str` has no length.

Comment: @hakre In that instance, it would be ample amounts faster to simply do a strlen check on `$str` and set `$char_array = array()` if `strlen` returns 0.

Answer (score 5):

`str_split` can do the trick. Note that strings in PHP can be accessed just like a character array. In most cases, you won't need to split your string into a "new" array.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example that works with multibyte (UTF-8) strings.

```
$str = 'äbcd';

// PHP 5.4.8 allows null as the third argument of mb_strpos() function
do {
    $arr[] = mb_substr( $str, 0, 1, 'utf-8' );
} while ( $str = mb_substr( $str, 1, mb_strlen( $str ), 'utf-8' ) );
```

It can be also done with [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) (`preg_split( '//u', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY )`), but unlike the above example, that runs almost as fast regardless of the size of the string, `preg_split()` is fast with small strings, but a lot slower with large ones.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$str = "Hello Friend";

$arr1 = str_split($str);
$arr2 = str_split($str, 3);

print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => H
    [1] => e
    [2] => l
    [3] => l
    [4] => o
    [5] =>
    [6] => F
    [7] => r
    [8] => i
    [9] => e
    [10] => n
    [11] => d
)

Array
(
    [0] => Hel
    [1] => lo
    [2] => Fri
    [3] => end
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $str = '546788';
    $char_array = preg_split('//', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the string, it's best to use:

```
$array = str_split($string);
```

When you have a delimiter, which separates the string, you can try,

```
explode('', $string);
```

Where you can pass the delimiter in the first variable inside the explode such as:

```
explode(',', $string);
```

Comment: Why try `explode('', $string);` if the OP already said that it makes PHP barf?

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = str_split("$string");
```

will actually work pretty fine, *but* if you want to preserve the special characters in that string, and you want to do some manipulation with them, *then* I would use

```
do {
    $array[] = mb_substr($string, 0, 1, 'utf-8');
} while ($string = mb_substr($string, 1, mb_strlen($string), 'utf-8'));
```

because for some of mine personal uses, it has been shown to be more reliable when there is an issue with special characters.

Comment: Please define what "special characters" means.  I know what you mean, but other researchers will not.  "THAN" should be "then".

Comment: Probably any character outside the ASCII.