# Number string to array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a string like '6554', and I would like to change this to an array, resembling the following:

```
Array([0] => 6, [1] => 5, [2] => 5, [3] => 4)
```

The problem is that I can not be certain of the length of the number and the number has nothing separating each digit. The number will not be negative or a float. Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: What's the matter with `str_split()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Split string into array, like explode with no delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170320/php-split-string-into-array-like-explode-with-no-delimiter) -- please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

How about using **[preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)**

```
$data=preg_split('//', $number, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

New way to do this

```
$str = '123456';
for($i=0 ; $i < strlen($str) ;$i++)
{
   $array[]=$str{$i};
}
```