# how to add letters of the name as array elements in php?

Tags: php, arrays

i am receiving the `name` from the `$request` in php.I want to do something like to add all the letters of the name in the array during the request e.g 
`$name=$_request['name'];`
`say $name='test';` 
i want to save it in an array in this format as `array("t","e","s","t")`. 
how can i do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Split string into array, like explode with no delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170320/php-split-string-into-array-like-explode-with-no-delimiter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the [php site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

so it would be like

```
$name= 'test';

$arr1 = str_split($name);
```

would result in a array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => t
    [1] => e
    [2] => s
    [3] => t
)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) is your friend.

```
$split_string = str_split($name);
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be sufficient for you to access the string directly as an array, without the need to format the data:

```
$a = 'abcde';
echo $a[2];
```

Will output

```
c
```

However you won't be able to perform some array operations, such as `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
$i = 0;
while(isset($name[$i])) {
 $nameArray[$i] = $name[$i];
 $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $letters = array();
  for (int $i=0; $i < strlen($name); $i++){

       $letters[] = $name[$i]; 

  }
```

and you can access it with:

```
   for (int $i=0; $i < strlen($letters); $i++){

        $letters[$i]; 
   }
```