# explode string by letter in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string in php like this one:

```
$string = "Count the character frequency of this string";
```

When I used explode function the output display as:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Count 
        [1] => the 
        [2] => character 
        [3] => frequency 
        [4] => of 
        [5] => this 
        [6] => string 
       )
```

But the output above doesn't satisfied me because I want to achieve an output which looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => C 
    [1] => o 
    [2] => u 
    [3] => n 
    [4] => t 
    [5] => t 
    [6] => h 
    [7] => e 
    [8] => c 
    [9] => h 
    [10] => a 
    [11] => r 
    [12] => a 
    [13] => c 
   )
```

I want to explode them by letter.

My question: Is it possible to do that? If it is, any suggestions. Thanks in advance

Comment: A few examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170320/php-split-string-into-array-like-explode-with-no-delimiter)..........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/str_split) after using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to get rid of the space characters:

```
 print_r(str_split(str_replace(' ', '', $string)));
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/305531)

If your string will contain other non alphanumeric characters you can use a regex to replace all non-alphanumeric characters:

```
print_r(str_split(preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', '', $string)));
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/305532)

Comment: Yeah, gotta love them demos ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the string as a character array by default in php

```
echo $string[0]
```

OUTPUTS

```
C
```