# "Empty delimiter" Warning when using PHP explode() function

Tags: php, split, explode, php-7

In javascript, `var myStringToArray = myString.split('');` is perfectly acceptable.

But in PHP, `$My_String_To_Array = explode('', $My_String);` throws an error:

> Warning: explode() Empty delimiter

The PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) explains:

> If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return **FALSE**.

So what *should* I be using in contemporary PHP instead of `explode('', $My_String)`?

So far, the alternatives I can see are:

- `split("", $My_String)` *- deprecated as of **PHP 5.3.0***
- `str_split($My_String)`
- `preg_split('//', $My_String)`

Seven years ago, `str_split()` would have been the correct alternative to use.

But is `str_split()` still in contemporary usage or should I only be looking at `preg_split()` ?

*Or should I be looking at something else?*

Comment: Do you want to explode on a space? If so, make a space? `explode(' ',$string)`. If you want to split a string into single characters, you can access that by doing `$string[0] ... $string[6]` and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Split string into array, like explode with no delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170320/php-split-string-into-array-like-explode-with-no-delimiter)

Comment: There're no warnings or other alerts on `str_split` man page, so yes, it can be used.

Comment: "So what should I be using in contemporary PHP..." Can you tell us exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) is perfectly valid. It is not deprecated and, most probably, it will never be. Don't mistake it for `split()` which is just an alias of `explode()`. [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) is not a replacement for `str_split()`. They have different arguments and work in different ways.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If dealing with multi-byte UTF-8 strings you should use:

```
$array = preg_split('//u', $My_String,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Otherwise you can just use:

```
$array = str_split($My_String);
```

The reason is noted in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php):

> **str_split()** will split into bytes, rather than characters when dealing with a multi-byte encoded string.

Starting from PHP version 7.4 the mbstring equivalent of str_split was added so you can now use:

```
$array = mb_str_split($my_string);
```

[`mb_str_split` manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-str-split.php)

Comment: A well-informed and comprehensive answer - thank you.

Answer (score 10):

I think str_split is what you are after

[str_split — Convert a string to an array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

```
<?php
$arr = str_split("Hello");
?>
```

will produce

```
Array
(
    [0] => H
    [1] => e
    [2] => l
    [3] => l
    [4] => o
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @MattJenkins. Can you confirm that `str_split()` still in contemporary usage? Is it still considered _best practice_ in April 2017?

Comment: No idea if it would be deemed best practice, however, I believe it does exactly what you require by design. Additionally, it's a valid and maintained method with no depreciation warnings.

Answer (score 2):

the first parameter is **required**.

```
explode(separator,string,limit)

[separator]: required;
[string]: required;
[limit]: alternative.
```

An explode function with a void [separator] is meaningless.

That's all.O(∩_∩)O~

Answer (score 2):

```php
//This will return error!!
 explode('', 'aaa');
//PHP Error:  explode(): Argument #1 ($separator) cannot be empty...

//Change to str_split
str_split('aaa');

[
     "a",
     "a",
     "a",
]
```